# Error in Compiling haskell .ll file with llvm backend

Tags: haskell, llvm, ghc, llvm-ir

I want to compile haskell using ghc front-end and llvm back-end.

I have following code in my haskell hello.hs file:

```
main = putStrLn "Hello World!"
```

I compile hello.hs with ghc using following command

```
ghc -fllvm -keep-llvm-files -force-recomp -hello.hs
```

which generate a hello.ll file along with other files.
I then try to compile this .ll file into a .bc file.

```
llvm-as hello.ll -o hello.bc
```

and then this .bc file to executable file

```
llc hello.bc -o hello
```

which generate an executable file. The problem is when I run this file I found the following error

```
./hello: line 1: .file: command not found
./hello: line 2: .section: command not found
./hello: line 3: .globl: command not found
./hello: line 4: .align: command not found
./hello: line 5: .type: command not found
./hello: line 6: Main_main2_info:: command not found
./hello: line 8: subq: command not found
./hello: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./hello: line 9: `                 movq                                                                      
%r13, 112(%rsp)'
```

and when I use lli on .bc file I get

```
main function not found in module error
```

I am running ghc and llvm on docker. I have version 3.4 of llvm and version 7.6.3 of ghc.

A "similar" error occur when I try to to do this on mac. I don't know why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

The `llc` program doesn't create executables.  It compiles LLVM bytecode to native assembly source (by default) or an object file.  If you run:

```
llc hello.bc -o hello
```

and then inspect the resulting "hello" file with a text editor, you'll see that it's an Intel assembly file, and the syntax errors you're getting are because you're trying to run it as a shell script.

Instead, you can compile the LLVM bytecode directly to an object file:

```
llc hello.bc -filetype=obj -o hello.o
```

and then try to link it into an executable:

```
ld hello.o -o hello
```

This will generate a bunch of linkage errors because it needs to be linked with the Haskell runtime.  It turns out that the best way to link in the Haskell runtime is to use `ghc` itself to do the linking:

```
ghc hello.o -o hello
```

Note that this command does *not* actually recompile the Haskell source.  It just does the linking.  If you want to see the linkage commands it runs, use:

```
ghc -v hello.o -o hello
```

and you'll understand why it's best to leave the linking to `ghc`!!

Finally, after all this, you should be able to run "hello".  The full set of commands is:

```
$ ghc -fllvm -keep-llvm-files -fforce-recomp hello.hs                                                           
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( hello.hs, hello.o )                                                       
Linking hello ...
$ rm hello                                                                                               
$ llvm-as hello.ll -o hello.bc                                                                                  
$ llc hello.bc -filetype=obj -o hello.o                                                                         
$ ghc hello.o -o hello                                                                                          
$ ./hello                                                                                                       
Hello, world!  
$
```

Comment: I am getting a segmentation fault when I run the hello file (I have tried it many times). Which version of ghc and llvm you are using?

Comment: Also why I am getting " 'main' function not found in module" error when I try to run "lli hello.bc". Is something missing in my .bc file?