# Compiled Haskell program to LLVM IR is missing main

Tags: haskell, compilation, llvm-ir, lli

following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52040651/compile-haskell-programs-to-llvm-ir) regarding the compilation of Haskell programs
to LLVM IR, I took the same Haskell program and tried to run its resulting LLVM IR code:

```
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
  where
    lesser  = filter (<  p) xs
    greater = filter (>= p) xs

main = print(quicksort([5,2,1,0,8,3]))
```

I first compiled it to LLVM IR with

```
$ ghc -keep-llvm-files main.hs
```

Then I transformed it to bitcode with:

```
$ llvm-as main.ll
```

However, when I tried to run it with `lli` I get the following error regarding a missing main:

```
$ lli main.bc
'main' function not found in module.
```

Am I doing something wrong? thanks.

EDIT: (from answer by K. A. Buhr)

```
$ ls -l main*
main.hs
$ ghc -keep-llvm-files main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )
Linking main ...
$ ls -l main*
main
main.hi
main.hs
main.ll
main.o
$ rm main main.hi main.o
$ llvm-as main.ll
$ llc main.bc -filetype=obj -o main.o
$ ghc -o main main.o
$ ./main
[0,1,2,3,5,8]
```

Comment: Perhaps [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46475029/7203016) will help you.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr thanks it works! I'm still a little confused because the created *.ll file must contain some kind of entry point right? it's not called main evidently, but it has got to exist no?  this "simple" haskell quicksort is 1706 lines long in the *.ll file so I couldn't find anything there. Also, could you please post as answer for me to accept?

Comment: There is an entry point but you need to be linked to the ghc runtime.

Comment: @DanRobertson how can I find it? I've grepped the *.ll file for "entry point" which always appears when I compile standard C files to *.bc and then to *.ll ... but there's no such thing there ... also grepped for `Main` (instead of main) which did find some results but they all seemed irrelevant

Comment: @OrenIshShalom I’m afraid I’ve no idea. There must be some way to find the functions in a `.ll` file but I don’t know what it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr.**  The entry point is (probably) named `ZCMain_main_closure`, and it's a data structure that references a block of code, rather than a block of code itself.  Still, it's interpretable by the Haskell runtime, and it corresponds directly to the Haskell "value" of the function `main :: IO ()` in your `main.hs` program.

The longer answer involves more than you ever wanted to know about linking programs, but here's the deal.  When you take a C program like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        printf("I like C!\n");
}
```

compile it to an object file with `gcc`:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c hello.c
```

and inspect the object file's symbol table:

```
$ nm hello.o
0000000000000000 T main
                 U printf
```

you will see that it contains a definition of the symbol `main` and an (undefined) reference to an external symbol `printf`.

Now, you might imagine that `main` is the "entry point" of this program.  Hah hah hah!  What a naive and silly thing for you to think!

In fact, real Linux gurus know that the entry point to your program isn't in the object file `hello.o` at all.  Where is it?  Well, it's in the ["C runtime"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0), a little file that gets linked in by `gcc` when you actually create your executable:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
0000000000000000 D __data_start
0000000000000000 W data_start
0000000000000000 R _IO_stdin_used
                 U __libc_csu_fini
                 U __libc_csu_init
                 U __libc_start_main
                 U main
0000000000000000 T _start
$
```

Note that this object file has an **undefined** reference to `main` which will be linked to your so-called entry point in `hello.o`.  It's this little stub defines the *real* entry point, namely `_start`.  You can tell this is the actual entry point because if you link the program into an executable, you'll see that the location of the `_start` symbol and the ELF entry point (which is the address to which the kernel actually first transfers control when you `execve()` your program) will coincide:

```
$ gcc -o hello hello.o
$ nm hello | egrep 'T _start'
0000000000400430 T _start
$ readelf -h hello | egrep Entry
Entry point address:               0x400430
```

All this is to say, the "entry point" of a program is actually a pretty complex concept.

When you compile and run a C program with the LLVM toolchain instead of GCC, the situation is all pretty similar.  That's by design to keep everything compatible with GCC.  The so-called entry point in your `hello.ll` file is just the C function `main`, and it's not the *real* entry point of your program.  That's still provided by the `crt1.o` stub.

Now, if we (finally) switch from talking about C to talking about Haskell, the Haskell runtime is, obviously, about a billion times more complicated than the C runtime, but it's been built on top of the C runtime.  So, when you compile a Haskell program the normal way:

```
$ ghc main.hs
stack ghc -- main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )
Linking main ...
$
```

you can see that the executable has an entry point named `_start`:

```
$ nm main | egrep 'T _start'
0000000000406560 T _start
```

which is actually the same C runtime stub as before that calls the C entry point:

```
$ nm main | egrep 'T main'
0000000000406dc4 T main
$
```

but *this* `main` is not your Haskell `main`.  This `main` is a C `main` function in a program dynamically created by GHC at link time.  You can look at such a program by running:

```
$ ghc -v -keep-tmp-files -fforce-recomp main.hs
```

and rummaging around for a file named `ghc_4.c` somewhere in a `/tmp` subdirectory:

```
$ cat /tmp/ghc10915_0/ghc_4.c
#include "Rts.h"
extern StgClosure ZCMain_main_closure;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 RtsConfig __conf = defaultRtsConfig;
 __conf.rts_opts_enabled = RtsOptsSafeOnly;
 __conf.rts_opts_suggestions = true;
 __conf.rts_hs_main = true;
 return hs_main(argc,argv,&ZCMain_main_closure,__conf);
}
```

Now, do you see that external reference to `ZCMain_main_closure`?  That, believe it or not, is the Haskell entry point for your program, and you should find it in `main.o`, whether you compiled using the vanilla GHC pipeline or via the LLVM backend:

```
$ egrep ZCMain_main_closure main.ll
%ZCMain_main_closure_struct = type <{i64, i64, i64, i64}>
...
```

Now, it's not a "function".  It's a specially formatted data structure (a closure) that the Haskell runtime system understands.  The `hs_main()` function above (yet another entry point!) is the main entry point into the Haskell runtime:

```
$ nm ~/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.4.3/lib/ghc-8.4.3/rts/libHSrts.a | egrep hs_main
0000000000000000 T hs_main
$
```

and it accepts a closure for a Haskell main function as the Haskell entry point to begin executing your program.

So, if you went through all this trouble in the hopes of isolating a Haskell program in an `*.ll` file that you could somehow run directly by jumping to its entry point, then I've got some bad news for you...  ;)

Comment: Great detailed answer!! step-by-step commands really help a lot to understand. Thanks for taking the time to write it, it is definitely one of the top answers I've read this year in SO.